# Send a message in indy TCP

Tags: delphi, indy

iam trying to send message like this

```
strMsg := Memo.Text;
Tclient.IOHandler.WriteLn(strMsg);
```

But how do i recive the text inside memo.text in server execute event?

Remy example is fine but how i do it with code like this

```
procedure TChatFo.SendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  strMsg: string;
begin
if tmemo.Text = '' then Abort;
strMsg := tmemo.Text;
Tcli.IOHandler.WriteLn(strMsg);
usertype.Clear;
end;
```

Comment: Have you tried `Text := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;` ?

Comment: ^^ will get you into trouble as server execute event does not run in the same thread context

Comment: Yes i tried that before but i receive nothing maybe thats because i use Multi receive event ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indy servers are multi-threaded.  Data is received in a worker thread, not the main UI thread.  Once you have read the incoming message data (using `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn`, for instance), you must then synchronize with the main thread if you want to display the message in a UI component.  You can use Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class for that synching, or use the anonymous procedure overloads of `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Notify()` if your version of Delphi has them available.

For example:

```
uses
  ..., IdSync;

type
  TMemoSync = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    FText: string;
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  end;

procedure TMemoSync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(FText);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Text: String;
begin
  Text := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn; 

  with TMemoSync.Create do
  try
    FText := Text;
    Synchronize;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Text: String;
begin
  Text := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn; 
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(Text);
    end
  );
end;
```